# How can I break the reading this text file (using ifstream)? C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I wanna stop the reading of my text input file when the word "synonyms" appears. I'm using ifstream and I don't know how to break the loop. I tried using a stringstream "synonyms" but it ended up junking my bst.  I included the complete project files below in case you wanna avoid typing.

Important part:

```
 for(;;)  /*here, I wanna break the cycle when it reads "synonyms"*/
               {

               inStream >> word;
               if (inStream.eof()) break;

               wordTree.insert(word);
               }

               wordTree.graph(cout);
```

dictionary.txt

```
   1 cute
    2 hello
    3 ugly
    4 easy
    5 difficult
    6 tired
    7 beautiful
    synonyms
    1 7
    7 1
    antonyms
    1 3
    3 1 7
    4 5
    5 4
    7 3
```

Project.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "MiBST.h"

using namespace std;

class WordInfo{

      public:
      //--id accesor
      int id ()const {return myId; } 

      /* myId is the number that identifies each word*/

      //--input function
      void read (istream &in)
      {
        in>>myId>>word;     
      }

      //--output function
      void print(ostream &out)
      {
          out<<myId<<" "<<word;     
      }

      //--- equals operator
     bool operator==(const WordInfo & otherword) const
     { return myId == otherword.myId; }

     //--- less-than operator
      bool operator<(const WordInfo & otherword) const
      { return myId < otherword.myId; }


      private:
              int myId;
              string word;

      };

      //--- Definition of input operator
      istream & operator>>(istream & in, WordInfo & word)
      {
           word.read(in);
      }

      //---Definition of output operator

      ostream & operator <<(ostream &out, WordInfo &word)
      {
            word.print(out);       
      }

      int main(){

          // Open stream to file of ids and words
          string wordFile;

          cout << "Enter name of dictionary file: ";
          getline(cin, wordFile);

          ifstream inStream(wordFile.data());



          if (!inStream.is_open())
          {
           cerr << "Cannot open " << wordFile << "\n";
           exit(1);
          }


          // Build the BST of word records
          BST<WordInfo> wordTree;   // BST of word records

          WordInfo word;            // a word record



          for(;;)  /*here, I wanna break the cycle when it reads "synonyms"*/
           {

           inStream >> word;
           if (inStream.eof()) break;

           wordTree.insert(word);
           }

           wordTree.graph(cout);

           //wordTree.inorder(cout);


          system ("PAUSE");
          return 0;

      }
```

MiBST.h (in case you wanna run it)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE




template <typename DataType>
class BST
{
 public:
  /***** Function Members *****/
  BST();

  bool empty() const;

  bool search(const DataType & item) const;

  void insert(const DataType & item);

  void remove(const DataType & item);

  void inorder(std::ostream & out) const;

  void graph(std::ostream & out) const;

  private:
  /***** Node class *****/
  class BinNode 
  {
   public:
    DataType data;
    BinNode * left;
    BinNode * right;

    // BinNode constructors
    // Default -- data part is default DataType value; both links are null.
    BinNode()
    : left(0), right(0)
    {}

    // Explicit Value -- data part contains item; both links are null.
    BinNode(DataType item)
    : data(item), left(0), right(0)
    {}


}; //end inner class

typedef BinNode * BinNodePointer; 

  /***** Private Function Members *****/
  void search2(const DataType & item, bool & found,
               BinNodePointer & locptr, BinNodePointer & parent) const;
 /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Locate a node containing item and its parent.

   Precondition:  None.
   Postcondition: locptr points to node containing item or is null if 
       not found, and parent points to its parent.#include <iostream>
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  void inorderAux(std::ostream & out, 
                  BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer subtreePtr) const;
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Inorder traversal auxiliary function.

    Precondition:  ostream out is open; subtreePtr points to a subtree 
        of this BST.
    Postcondition: Subtree with root pointed to by subtreePtr has been
        output to out.
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  void graphAux(std::ostream & out, int indent,
                      BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer subtreeRoot) const;
  /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Graph auxiliary function.

    Precondition:  ostream out is open; subtreePtr points to a subtree 
        of this BST.
    Postcondition: Graphical representation of subtree with root pointed 
        to by subtreePtr has been output to out, indented indent spaces.
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 /***** Data Members *****/
  BinNodePointer myRoot; 

}; // end of class template declaration

//--- Definition of constructor
template <typename DataType>
inline BST<DataType>::BST()
: myRoot(0)
{}

//--- Definition of empty()
template <typename DataType>
inline bool BST<DataType>::empty() const
{ return myRoot == 0; }

//--- Definition of search()
template <typename DataType>
bool BST<DataType>::search(const DataType & item) const
{
   typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer locptr = myRoot;

   typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer parent =0;

/*   BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer locptr = myRoot;
   parent = 0; */ //falta el typename en la declaracion original

   bool found = false;
   while (!found && locptr != 0)
   {
      if (item < locptr->data)       // descend left
        locptr = locptr->left;
      else if (locptr->data < item)  // descend right
        locptr = locptr->right;
      else                           // item found
        found = true;
   }
   return found;
}

//--- Definition of insert()
template <typename DataType>
inline void BST<DataType>::insert(const DataType & item)
{
   typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer 
        locptr = myRoot,   // search pointer
        parent = 0;        // pointer to parent of current node
   bool found = false;     // indicates if item already in BST
   while (!found && locptr != 0)
   {
      parent = locptr;
      if (item < locptr->data)       // descend left
         locptr = locptr->left;
      else if (locptr->data < item)  // descend right
         locptr = locptr->right;
      else                           // item found
         found = true;
   }
   if (!found)
   {                                 // construct node containing item


      locptr = new typename BST<DataType>::BinNode(item);  
      if (parent == 0)               // empty tree
         myRoot = locptr;
      else if (item < parent->data )  // insert to left of parent
         parent->left = locptr;
      else                           // insert to right of parent
         parent->right = locptr;
   }
   else
      std::cout << "Item already in the tree\n";
}

//--- Definition of remove()
template <typename DataType>
void BST<DataType>::remove(const DataType & item)
{
   bool found;                      // signals if item is found
   typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer 
      x,                            // points to node to be deleted
      parent;                       //    "    " parent of x and xSucc
   search2(item, found, x, parent);

   if (!found)
   {
      std::cout << "Item not in the BST\n";
      return;
   }
   //else
   if (x->left != 0 && x->right != 0)
   {                                // node has 2 children
      // Find x's inorder successor and its parent
      typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer xSucc = x->right;
      parent = x;
      while (xSucc->left != 0)       // descend left
      {
         parent = xSucc;
         xSucc = xSucc->left;
      }

     // Move contents of xSucc to x and change x 
     // to point to successor, which will be removed.
     x->data = xSucc->data;
     x = xSucc;
   } // end if node has 2 children

   // Now proceed with case where node has 0 or 2 child
   typename BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer 
      subtree = x->left;             // pointer to a subtree of x
   if (subtree == 0)
      subtree = x->right;
   if (parent == 0)                  // root being removed
      myRoot = subtree;
   else if (parent->left == x)       // left child of parent
      parent->left = subtree; 
   else                              // right child of parent
      parent->right = subtree;
   delete x;
}

//--- Definition of inorder()
template <typename DataType>
inline void BST<DataType>::inorder(std::ostream & out) const
{ 
   inorderAux(out, myRoot); 
}

//--- Definition of graph()
template <typename DataType>
inline void BST<DataType>::graph(std::ostream & out) const
{ graphAux(out, 0, myRoot); }

//--- Definition of search2()
template <typename DataType>
void BST<DataType>::search2(const DataType & item, bool & found,
                            BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer & locptr, 
                            BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer & parent) const
{
   locptr = myRoot;
   parent = 0;
   found = false;
   while (!found && locptr != 0)
   {
      if (item < locptr->data)       // descend left
      {
         parent = locptr;
         locptr = locptr->left;
      }
      else if (locptr->data < item)  // descend right
      {
         parent = locptr;
         locptr = locptr->right;
      }
      else                           // item found
         found = true;
   }
}
//--- Definition of inorderAux()
template <typename DataType>
void BST<DataType>::inorderAux(std::ostream & out, 
                               BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer subtreeRoot) const
{
   if (subtreeRoot != 0)
   {
      inorderAux(out, subtreeRoot->left);    // L operation
      out << subtreeRoot->data << "  ";      // V operation
      inorderAux(out, subtreeRoot->right);   // R operation
   }
}


//--- Definition of graphAux()


template <typename DataType>
void BST<DataType>::graphAux(std::ostream & out, int indent, 
                             BST<DataType>::BinNodePointer subtreeRoot) const
{
  if (subtreeRoot != 0)
    {
      graphAux(out, indent + 8, subtreeRoot->right);
      out << std::setw(indent) << " " << subtreeRoot->data << std::endl;
      graphAux(out, indent + 8, subtreeRoot->left);
    }
}


#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like

```
/* here, it stops when reading "synonyms" or when failing to extract a word. */
while(inStream >> word && word != "synonym") {
    wordTree.insert(word);
}
wordTree.graph(cout);
```

Note that when it fails to read a sequence of non-whitespace characters, it sets the fail-bit of the stream. inStream evaluates to false then. That is what makes the loop work. Be careful when using `.eof();` It only returns true after you tried to read beyond the end of file. So for example, you will exit the loop, and miss the word *3 tree* here:

```
1 house 2 garden 3 tree
```

Assuming there is no white-space after *tree*. The same will of course happen if you have newlines between the word information and have no trailing newline after the last word. Using `if(inStream)` (which the while loop does implicitly) is safe. It would still evaluate to true in this case, and only to false if it didn't read anything except white-space.

Answer (score 4):

You should make an operator == on WordInfo to compare it to a string, then you can just this in the reading loop:

```
if ( word == "synonyms" ) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

@SoapBox:

I created this == operator:

```
 //--- equals operator for String
     bool operator==(const string & aString) const
     { return word == aString; } // word is the WordInfo string field for 'real' word
```

And changed the for(;;) to:

```
for(;;)
           {


           inStream >> word;
           if (word=="synonyms") break;

           wordTree.insert(word);
           }
```

And ended up with an infinite loop printing:

```
"Item already in the tree"
```

Btw, I previoulsy tested the tree with a sample dictionary like this and it worked.

```
dict2.txt
```

1 cute
2 hello
3 ugly
4 easy
5 difficult
6 tired
7 beautiful